# Atualizar valor de pagina VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Acabei esbarrando em um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Ao criar uma pagina `detalhes`, eu a chamo usando

`this.$router.push({name: 'Detalhes'})`

E passo um parametro

`this.$router.push({name: 'Detalhes', params: {dados: this.dados}})`

O problema é, eu estando nessa pagina já, ela não é recarregada.

Explicando melhor, tenho um componente que chamo de `menu`, nesse componente tenho uma lista de links que chama uma API alterando o conteudo do meio, quando clico a primeira vez em um dos links do menu, funciona normalmente, mas quando já estou na pagina e clico em outro link, ele não passa novamente o valor para a pagina `detalhes`.